# Terminology - does declaring methods in different namespaces count as overloading

Tags: c#, oop, namespaces, overloading, terminology

Basically, the question has been summed up in the title. If we have two methods/functions with the same signature (i.e. same name, parameters type and order, generics type parameters number) in different namespaces, does this count as overloading?

This is a C# question, but I'd love to find an answer for different OOP languages.

Also, another question. If we have two methods with the same signature, but in different classes, would that count as overloading?

Comment: I don't think that quantifies overloading. While they have the same name if they differ in namespace or class they, according to [Member Overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029(v=vs.110).aspx) from Microsoft, are not overloads.

Comment: You can't declare a method directly in a namespace.

Comment: As @Blorgbeard pointed out this does not sound like C# question as what you describe is not possible in C# (at least up to 5) due to lack of global methods. You may want to clarify what you are talking about with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading happens when you have multiple methods in the current class that have the same name but different signature. The scope of method overloading is "Within the current class"

```
public class Math2
{
 // This one's for squares
 public static double Area(double side)
 {
  return side * side; 
 }

 // This one's for rectangles
 public static double Area(double length, double height)
 {
  return length * height; 
 }
}
```

If the methods are in different classes, it is not considered overloading.
It's important to mention that overloading is only with parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds logical